# Setting environment variable 'TURTLEBOT_STAGE_MAP_FILE'

Tags: ros, gazebo, simulation, roslaunch, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to get the turtlebot stage simulator running from these instructions:
http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot_stage/Tutorials/indigo/Bring%20up%20TurtleBot%20in%20stage

But, putting the first line in the terminal:

```
roslaunch turtlebot_stage turtlebot_in_stage.launch
```

gives this output:

```
... logging to /home/yaseen-14/.ros/log/0b120c28-319b-11e5-ac3b-685d4316eccf/roslaunch-yaseen14-HP-Pavilion-m6-Notebook-PC-11910.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

Invalid <arg> tag: environment variable 'TURTLEBOT_STAGE_MAP_FILE' is not set. 

Arg xml is <arg default=" $(env TURTLEBOT_STAGE_MAP_FILE)" name="map_file"/>
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

Not sure why this is happening but would appreciate if anyone could help me out. Cheers!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/214452/setting-environment-variable-%27turtlebot_stage_map_file%27/) by [ymn93](https://answers.ros.org/users/23327/ymn93/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2015-07-23

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had this problem too, the next tutorial teaching you how to [customise turtlebot_stage](http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot_stage/Tutorials/indigo/Customizing%20the%20Stage%20Simulator) gives you some clues but when I tried to set the world and map files via the command line it still failed. Setting the environment variables in the terminal did work though.

(note: this may not be the best method, but it works and won't hurt anything)

You will find the required files in the `turtlebot_stage` directory, copy the map files to your home directory (you need to copy them to your home directory for permission reasons).
Note that your path may differ from mine e.g. I'm using ROS Indigo.

Copy this directory `/opt/ros/indigo/share/turtlebot_stage/maps/` to something like `~/stageTurorial/maps/`

Then set some environment variables from your terminal

```
export TURTLEBOT_STAGE_WORLD_FILE="~/stageTutorial/maps/stage/maze.world"
export TURTLEBOT_STAGE_MAP_FILE="~/stageTutorial/maps/maze.yaml"
```

Now launching `turtlebot_stage` should work

```
roslaunch turtlebot_stage turtlebot_in_stage.launch
```

---

Originally posted by [Joelf](https://answers.ros.org/users/23722/joelf/) with karma: 46 on 2015-08-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jacksonkr_](https://answers.ros.org/users/21619/jacksonkr_/) on 2016-02-13**:
this works for indigo on osx

**Comment by [necip](https://answers.ros.org/users/52000/necip/) on 2020-02-22**:
for kinetic too, thanks a lot.

`export TURTLEBOT_STAGE_WORLD_FILE="/opt/ros/kinetic/share/turtlebot_stage/maps/stage/maze.world"`

`export TURTLEBOT_STAGE_MAP_FILE="/opt/ros/kinetic/share/turtlebot_stage/maps/maze.yaml"`

`roslaunch turtlebot_stage turtlebot_in_stage.launch`

worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[Note : I use ROS Indigo,Ubuntu 14.04]
I had this problem too. I had tried Joelf's answer in my Indigo but the error info still exists which always said that it can not find the "maze.world" and "maze.yaml" even if I had put them into right directory.Thanks a lot for Joelf's answer which has inspired me.
http://answers.ros.org/users/23722/joelf/

I found an easier way that may help.
Just look at this directory:

```
/opt/ros/indigo/share/turtlebot_stage/maps/
```

(Open the contents of the file system and you will found this folder)

You will find several map files including "maze.yaml" and a folder: "stage", in which there are 3 files including "maze.world".(Sorry but there must be something wrong with my image uploader)

Then set environment variables in terminal:

```
export TURTLEBOT_STAGE_WORLD_FILE="/opt/ros/indigo/share/turtlebot_stage/maps/stage/maze.world"
export TURTLEBOT_STAGE_MAP_FILE="/opt/ros/indigo/share/turtlebot_stage/maps/maze.yaml"
```

Then launch:

```
roslaunch turtlebot_stage turtlebot_in_stage.launch
```

Note: If there are still some errors, remember to update your source list and use
`sudo apt-get update`,then install the package `sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-turtlebot-rviz-launchers`,just guarantee  your packages are the newest. By the way, I had used Ubuntu 12 before but there are something wrong with the source list even after sudo update, I can not run the turtlebot, the same error. After I update to Ubuntu 14.04, everything is OK.

---

Originally posted by [Shouren Wu](https://answers.ros.org/users/26014/shouren-wu/) with karma: 41 on 2016-02-20

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [karthik valliappan](https://answers.ros.org/users/44707/karthik-valliappan/) on 2019-08-09**:
worked fine for ROS kinetic

**Comment by [Anchellon](https://answers.ros.org/users/40786/anchellon/) on 2019-09-04**:
Note:just change the version of ROS depending on what you are using